# Get user email on newsletter click with utm parameters

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I want to get the user's email when they click on a link sent to them on a newsletter.
So the user clicks the link and that link will send the user to a website that contains the url: www.example.com/?utm_source.....
So my question which utm parameter I should use to get the user email so that the email will be displayed on the url
 i.e www.example.com/?utm_content=test@test.com so I can show this particual user a different content from other users?

I created a campaign but don't know how to get user's email

Thanks for any help

Comment: Have you checked this article - [Campaigns and traffic sources](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6205762?hl=en) ?

Answer (score 0):

Passing emails onto Google Analytics is currently against their [PII policy](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6366371?hl=en).

You will need to track it using the tracking code of your CRM system.